# Index of Selected Row in a Section

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a Food Items separated by sections and I want to be able to press on the food item and go to a food item detail page.  My problem is that I am not able to pass the information to the detail because I am not getting the index of the item in the section.
FoodItem is from coredata.

```
 var allFoodItems = [[FoodItem]]()
 var foodItemTypes = [
FoodItemType.Appetizer.rawValue,
FoodItemType.SoupSalad.rawValue,
FoodItemType.Main.rawValue]

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let foodItem = FoodItem()
    guard let section = foodItemTypes.index(of: foodItem.type!) else { return }

    let row = allFoodItems[section].count

    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)

    let foodItemDetailController = FoodItemDetailController()
    foodItemDetailController.foodItem = selectedIndexPath
    navigationController?.pushViewController(foodItemDetailController, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to send indexPath directly

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let foodItemDetailController = FoodItemDetailController()

    foodItemDetailController.foodItem = indexPath   // if  IndexPath is the type 

    navigationController?.pushViewController(foodItemDetailController, animated: true)
}
```

//

Or send the item clicked

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let all = allFoodItems[indexPath.section]

    let item = all[indexPath.row]

    let foodItemDetailController = FoodItemDetailController()

    foodItemDetailController.foodItem = item // if foodItem is the type

    navigationController?.pushViewController(foodItemDetailController, animated: true)
}
```